# Excel MAX condition between two column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Example a table look like this,

[image: Sample Table]

Col A and Col B in this example (it can be more than two columns) has its own respective background cell color. In column "**C**", I use `=MAX(A2, B2)` etc. to get the max value between the two. However, I also want the formatting color to be picked up (copied) following the max value from each of the respective column as well. If **A** is the MAX value then the cell background will be from **A** and if **B** then it will be from **B**. Also, if the value of the two **A** and **B** are the same (or if more than two columns, all of the value should be the same), then the color will be red as an example.

I have tried using conditional formatting but I cannot make it work and was hoping without a VB script. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What CF have you tried to apply? Looks like you just need to apply three rules based on some simple formula.

Comment: Agree with @JvdV. This seems fairly straightforward for conditional formatting. Getting conditional formatting can be tricky and won't work if you don't use the $ correctly to specify what you want formatted. For formatting Col C you would want the condition to be =$A2=$B2 and the area formatted will be $C2:$Cx. Try that and see if it works, then apply the rules and formatting needed for cols A & B.

Comment: @DavidRichardson the Max value can be from Col A or Col B. Col A and B has its own respective color. What I want in Col C is to capture the Max value (which I use =MAX(A,B) for the formula) and also to pick the color of that column. It can be from A and it can be from B.

Comment: @RizaMarhaban Got it. For Col C you need 3 conditional formatting rules similar to what is shown in the answer below. You need one rule with the condition Col C = Col A, one for Col C = Col B, and one Col A = Col B (or Col A, B, C all equal each other - same thing). Then make the formatting the color you need to match Col A and Col B.

Comment: @DavidRichardson I think I may need a macro for this. Looks like there is no out of the box function to do this. My example is two column, but actually can be more than two columns to get he max value where each column has different colors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need three rules for three different color. Try-

```
=$A1>$B1 'For yellow
=$A1<$B1 'For light green
=$A1=$B1 'For red
```

[image]

Comment: No. The logic should be in the Column C. Column C is using =MAX(A, B). The color of Column A and Column B are one color respectively. But in Column C  other than the MAX value picked up, it should pick the color as well based on the Max value between the two.

Comment: @RizaMarhaban You can apply formatting to `Column C` instead of A & B

Comment: I need to use MAX. In this example only 2 column but it can be more than two.

Comment: And it needs to pick the color of that column not assigning it.

Comment: @RizaMarhaban If you're setting the colors for Col A and Col B you can use those same colors in your conditional formatting. There is no function to read the color of a cell and copy it. You would need to use an Excel macro to do this.

Comment: @DavidRichardson I agree with you. I don't think there is a function out of the box without a macro for this scenario.